# find text inside file and display complete output

Tags: search, logging, find, text-files

I am searching for a certain kind of error in hundreds of log files, each log has 10 thousands of lines.  I'm looking for lines with certain keywords, this I was able to do with WindowsGrep (awesome tool but) I am not just searching, I want to produce a complete output for each line, copy everything from all the files and dump that in excel for research.

The whole output must be listed in the find pane, and not just show a bit of the lines where my keyword is located.

For example this is what I typically get:

File A - Line 20002 - "..search **term**... this  sen..."

This is what I need:

"The search **term** is in this complete sentence." file name and line are ok, not very important

Can you recommend something that you have used to produce something like the above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
findstr "textToSearch" x:\wherever\*.log > outputfile.txt
```

Or you can

```
findstr "textToSearch" x:\wherever\*.log | clip
```

and all text will be in clipboard, just to paste in excel

`/N` argument of findstr will show line numbers.

Something i've used ? I use findstr (usually for batch files wich will not run on my pc), grep, awk, sed, tr, gsar and less from gnuwin32 and logparser from Microsoft. Gnu tools are incredible usefull in windows. Logparser allow to write queries (SQL!) against your log files.

Comment: This was useful. I also found a tool already installed that is created particularly for sharepoint horrendous logs, the name is Sharepoint logviewer. It is heavey on the server resources so i have to search 10 days at a time! Thanks!